# Why can't I import test modules directly into other tests in elixir

Tags: testing, import, elixir, synchronous, ex-unit

I spent days trying to figure out how to import my test modules into a master test module so I could run them synchronously and I finally found my solution at the link below:

[Importing test code in elixir unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652439/importing-test-code-in-elixir-unit-test)

My question is - WHY does this have to be a work-around? Why won't elixir allow me to directly alias or import my test modules into my test_suite.exs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR:

- It doesn't have to be a workaround :)
- Elixir just relies on the [`:elixirc_paths`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Compile.Elixir.html#module-configuration) variable, defaulting to `["lib"]`, to determine where to find files to be compiled.

A standard way to do this, which is done by default by [`mix phx.new`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/b27dbb24119540b07a039b730de40bd206aed3d3/installer/templates/phx_single/mix.exs#L30-L32) if you work with Phoenix for instance, is to add the following to your `mix.exs`:

```elixir
  def project do
    [
      ...,
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env())
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]
```

Then every module defined in a `.ex` file (not `.exs`!) within `test/support/` will be compiled when running your test suite.

Comment: This is the correct answer, unlike the ugly hack dated 2015 which is linked in OP :)